# Overwriting the class object using istream overloading

Tags: c++

Here I'm trying to overwrite the inventory objects, but when I run the second `std::cout` it print the old value again, I want it to write the inputted value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class inventory
{
private:
    std::string item;
    int onhand;
    double cost;

public:
    inventory(std::string i, int o, double c){
        item = i;
        onhand = o;
        cost = c;
    }
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, inventory entity){
    stream << entity.item << "\t" << entity.onhand << "\t" << entity.cost << std::endl;
    return stream;
}
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, inventory entity){
    stream >> entity.item >> entity.onhand >> entity.cost;
    return stream;
}
};

int main()
{
    inventory obj("hammer", 12, 2000);
    std::cout << obj;
    std::cin >> obj;
    std::cout << obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass `inventory entity` by value. Try to modify your input stream function so that you pass the `obj` by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is, that you pass your `inventory obj` by value

What you want is passing it as reference like so:

`friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, inventory &entity)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator>>` accepts a copy of object and modifies that copy. You need to pass by reference:

```cpp
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, inventory entity);
```